# Simple DOM cloneNode issue

Tags: dom, clonenode

im having another rather simple issue with using cloneNode. I'm trying to duplicate a li node back into its own ul using java and I can't seem to find why its not working. 
I have tried multiple things but I cant for the life of me figure it out.
I want this:

```
                        <ul id="mylist">
                            <li><h3>My Image:<img src="myImage.png"></h3></li>
                        </ul>
```

To look like this:
`<ul id="mylist">
                                <li><h3>My Image:<img src="myImage.png"></h3></li>
                                <li><h3>My Image:<img src="myImage.png"></h3></li>
                            </ul>`

I am using this function:

```
                        function myFunction(){
                                    parent=document.getElementById("myList");
                                    child=parent.getElementbyTagName("li")[0];
                                    clone= child.cloneNode(true);
                                    parent.insertBefore(clone,child);   
                        } 
                        </script>
```

Unsure as to why its not working, I pulled the code almost identically from an online source. If someone could help with my newbie question I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I often find when copying javascript from the inter-rent, the author has never checked his code for typing errors or maybe they're deliberate to encourage a bit of understanding.

This works:

```
<ul id="myawesomelist">
  <li id="x"><h3>My awesome image:<img src="myawesomeimage.png"></h3></li>
</ul>
```

and here's the javascript:

```
function myawesomefunction()
{
 var myawesomeparent=document.getElementById('myawesomelist');
 var myawesomechild=myawesomeparent.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
 var myawesomeclone=myawesomechild.cloneNode(true);
 myawesomeparent.insertBefore(myawesomeclone,myawesomechild);
}
```

And here's the fiddle I built it in:

http://jsfiddle.net/g51n8sor/